# "Run at Startup" using helper app recently stopped working(CLOSED)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am using [ServiceManagement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/servicemanagement/1657389-smloginitem.h?language=objc), `SMLoginItem`

if anybody is using "Run at Startup" in their app please check your app and help me to identify if the problem is with my app or with the API.

```
if(!SMLoginItemSetEnabled((__bridge CFStringRef)@"myAppBundleIdentifier", (BOOL)[sender state]))
{
   NSLog(@"Dagnabit!");
}
```

Comment: Implementing *Run at Startup* is a bit more than checking `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`

Comment: yaa it is working fine.. But Little delay if we use workspace. I removed my workspace and directly using project.